# Unable to make post request using request library python

Tags: python

I am trying to use requests module in python to communicate with a rest server

This is what I am trying to do:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
data = {'foo':'foo','bar':'bar'}
r = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/foo",headers=headers,data=json.dumps(data))
print r.text
u'Resource representation is only available with these Content-Types:\napplication/json; charset=UTF-8'
```

How do I resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Try this header: `headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change headers to:

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}
```

**upd**: I think the most correct headers would be:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
```

Comment: With your suggestion, I get this response "u'Resource representation is only available with these Content-Types:\ntext/plain; charset=UTF-8\ntext/plain"

Comment: I tried this headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'} and it gave The server was not able to produce a timely response to your request

Comment: how with `headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}` or without headers?

Comment: with this option.. i get u"There was a problem with the requests Content-Type:\nExpected 'application/json'"